# Strange behavior of scipy.cKDTree.sparse_distance_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, kdtree

I am trying to calculate mutual distance of a set of points using `scipy.cKDTree.sparse_distance_matrix`. Eventually I would like to use this for `10**6` points in dimensions as high as `15`, but as an example, for 15 data points in two dimension, we expect that the distance matrix has 15*15 elements where 15 of them are zero. Therefore there are 210 non-zero elements in the matrix. But `sparse_distance_matrix` returns only 160 non-zero values:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
NP=15
dimension=2
seed=1
state = np.random.RandomState(seed)
pts=state.random_sample([NP,dimension]) 
tree=cKDTree(pts)
f = cKDTree.sparse_distance_matrix(tree,tree,5.)
print np.vstack(f.nonzero()).T.shape[0]
```

> 160

I do not understand what I am missing. Note that I have set `max_distance` at 5.0 but the longest distance possible is `sqrt(2)` so that should not replace any entry by zero. I'm using `SciPy` version '0.13.3`.

**Edit**:

Updating to 0.16 solved the problem.

Comment: When I run your code with scipy 0.16.0 (and numpy 1.10.1), `210` is printed.

Comment: The first two issues found by this search look relevant: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/search?q=sparse_distance_matrix&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: It should be a bug then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) mentioned in his comment, this was due to an [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2353) in older versions of scipy. In `scipy 0.16` everything is good!